# Access dynamic created objects properties in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

In my QML GUI Objects are created during runtime by a javascript.
How can I access the properties of these dynamically created objects. There is no information about this in the QML manual (http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdeclarativedynamicobjects.html)

My traget id to change the properties after creation and store them with Qt.labs.settings so my programm saves the created objects and can create these objects again on startup.

Creating the object with CreateSquareGaugeScript.createRect() works, but I cant find a way to access its properties after that.

As requested my short simple example.

main.cpp:

```
    import QtQuick 2.9
    import QtQuick.Window 2.2
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
    import "qrc:/script.js" as MyScript

    Window {
        id: mainWindow
        visible: true
        width: 640
        height: 480
        title: qsTr("Hello World")

        Button {
            id: button
            x: 540
            y: 0
            text: qsTr("Button")
            onClicked: MyScript.createRect()
        }

    }

main.qml

import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import "qrc:/script.js" as MyScript

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button {
        id: button
        x: 540
        y: 0
        text: qsTr("Button")
        onClicked: MyScript.createRect()
    }

}
```

That object that get's created:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 50
    height: 50
    Drag.active: true

    MouseArea {
        id: touchArea
        anchors.fill: parent

        drag.target: parent
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 50
        height: 50
        color: "#ad0000"
    }

}
```

And the script:

```
var component;
var gauge;

function createRect() {
    component = Qt.createComponent("rect.qml");
    if (component.status === Component.Ready){
        finishCreation();
    }
    else {
        component.statusChanged.connect(finishCreation);
        console.log("component not ready!");
    }
}

function finishCreation() {
    if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
        gauge = component.createObject(mainWindow);
        if (gauge === null) {
            // Error Handling
            console.log("Error creating object");
        }

    } else if (component.status === Component.Error) {
        // Error Handling
        console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
    }
}
```

The objects get's created as often as the user wants to. How can I access the properties from the created objects from QML and store them afterwards in settings to I can recreate the objects after programm start

Comment: use `gauge.your_property`

Comment: When creating the object from QML by calling the javascript, there is no ID that I can call from QML. gauge.property would only work in the javascript?

Comment: it will also work in QML, you can provide a [mcve] to point out how to do it (shows the main.qml and squaregauge.qml)

Comment: https://github.com/BastianGschrey/stackoverflow/tree/master/54296349 you can see it here.

Comment: When I execute your code I do not see anything, at least I expected to see the gauge. please provide a [mcve], external links are not recommended because if they break your question is useless.

Comment: The value that you *should return* from your functions by calling to component.createObject is the same as `id`. Just store the value and access a property by id.property in the same way as you do with statically created object.

Comment: Btw the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createComponent-method) is pretty clear

Comment: The Documentation shows how you return a value when you call createObject directly from QML. But wenn I call the JS with "var myobject = myscript.creatfunction()" myobject is "undefined"but the object is created succesfully. So for me its not pretty clear

Comment: what is `myscript.creatfunction()`?

Comment: look at my example on top.

Comment: How to use with `alias` ??